# Get telegram channel messages after an specific id with telethon

Tags: telethon

I want to get a specific channel posts after an id (ex. 1245). I write this code:

```
# After connection to session in cli variable
last_post = cli(
                GetHistoryRequest(
                    peer=entity,
                    limit=100,
                    offset_date=None,
                    add_offset=0,
                    hash=0
                )
            )
```

But this gives me the 100 last message. Even with the `max_id` argument passed to the GetHistoryRequest, I get the messages from the earlier message to older ones. How can I get messages with opposite order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must read the doc first and then ask your question.
You can do it simply with the `iter_messages` argument as follow:

```
next_post = cli.iter_messages(
                entity,
                limit=5,
                min_id=your_post_id,
                reverse=True
            )
```

with the `reverse` argument you can get the posts with the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using bot (mostly the same for client version of the code)

```py
    bot = TelegramClient('bot', API_ID, API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)
    result = await bot(functions.messages.GetMessagesRequest(id=[message_id]))
    message = result.messages[0]
    print(message.text)
```

To get a chat/full chat

```py
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage)
    async def any_message_arrived_handler(event):
        chat = await event.get_chat()
        full_chat = await bot(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
            chat_id=chat.id
        ))
```

The best place to look is [the documentation](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/index.html). Just search page for `messages` and you will find what you need with examples included.